# Disable automatized event prototypes generation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have large number of buttons in my `Windows Form Application`. Each button has its own *event handler function* and together they have more than 1500 lines.

I want all those *"callback"* functions moved into separate file (I can do that using `partial class MainForm`), but Visual Studio will create prototypes of all 35 event handler in main form file (code won't compile because of multiple definitions of the same functions inside `MainForm`) each time I use Form Designer (set different label and so on).

**My question is** how can I prevent Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 from recreating those prototypes over and over again?

Example of *event handler prototype*:

```
private void exportSelectedItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by prototypes?  If you move the button event handlers they are recreated?  Can you provide example of one?

Comment: @Kami I've added an example... And yes, when I move handlers they are recreaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio, for whatever reason, will create the event handlers if the do not exist in the file directly associated with the form designer.  This only happens when there is a change made on the form.

This results in the behaviour above.

You can however, manually add the event handlers through code rather than through the designer in the constructor or a custom init function.

for example,

```
public MainForm()
{
   exportSelectedItems.Click += new EventHandler(exportSelectedItems_Click);
}
```

Comment: That may be difficult for my colleagues to read, but it now occurred to me that I can keep "callbacks" inside main file and move everything else into my separate file ;)